# Getting range of numbers from a (sorted) list of numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I came across the following problem:
Consider having an ascending list of numbers (e.g. 1,2,3,7,8,10),
gather the ranges (of consecutive numbers) and print them in a compact form like (with the numbers given above):

1->3
7->8
10

In particular, the solution should also work well with "degenerated cases" like list of just one element, or a list like -2,1.

I came up with a solution, where I tried to separate the numbers into different vectors, which however looks quite cumbersome. So, I would like to know if there is a better alternative approach to that problem.

Here is my approach:

```
vector< vector<int> > result(numbers.size()*numbers.size(), vector<int>());

int last_range;
vector<int> range;
vector<string> result_string;

//1,2,3,7,8,10

if(numbers.size() == 1) 
{
    stringstream ss; 

    ss << numbers[0];

    result_string.push_back(ss.to_string());

    return result_string;

}


for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++ )
{

    if( numbers[i] - numbers[i-1] == 1 ) 
    {
        range.push_back(numbers[i]);
    }

    if ( i == numbers.size()-1 ) 
    {
        last_range = numbers[i];
        range.push_back(last_range);
    }

    result[i-1].push_back(range);
} 

if( result.size() < 1 )
{
    range.push_back(numbers[0]);

    result[0].push_back(range);

    stringstream ss; 
    ss << result[0][0];

    result_string.push_back(ss.to_string());

    return result_string;
}

//result[0] - > array of numbers  1,2,3 
// result [1] - > array of numbers


for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++ )
{
        int start_index = result[i][0];
        int last_index  = result[i][result.size()-1]; 

        stringstream ss_startindex; 
        stringstream ss_endindex; 

        ss_startindex << result[i][0];
        ss_endindex  << result[i][result.size()-1];
        string result = ss_startindex.to_string() + "->" + ss_endindex.to_string();
        result_string.push_back(result);

}       

return result_string;
}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Most interview questions are about how you go about understanding the problem and working to a solution.   Did you ask any questions, such as *why* the interviewer thought printing values in that way was useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an object that carries context ('next integer is part of a range?') across, while you iterate over a sequence. So this kind of problem is best solved with function object used as a *unary function* with the `std::for_each` algorithm.

A working example would be:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include <iostream>

using IntCollection = std::vector<int>;

IntCollection is = {1,2,3,7,8,10}, is2 = {-2,1}, is3 = {20};

using Range = std::pair<int,int>;

class IntRangePrinter
{
public:
    void operator() (int i)
    {
        if (r.first == inval)
            r.first = i;
        else if (r.second == inval && r.first + 1 == i)
            r.second = i;
        else if (r.second + 1 == i)
            r.second = i;
        else {
            print_range_or_value();
            // reset after printing
            reset();
            // and re-init range with current value
            r.first = i;
        }
    }

    // There might be "pending" data to be printed
    void flush()
    {
        print_range_or_value();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        reset();
    }

private:
    static int inval; // some value not to be expected in IntCollection
    void print_range_or_value()
    {
        if (r.first != inval && r.second != inval)
            std::cout << ' ' << r.first << "->" << r.second;
        else // if (r.second == inval)
            std::cout << ' ' << r.first;
    }
    void reset ()
    {
        r.first = inval;
        r.second = inval;
    }

    Range r = {inval,inval};

};

int IntRangePrinter::inval = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

int main () {
    IntRangePrinter p;
    p = std::for_each(is.begin(), is.end(), std::move(p));
    p.flush();

    p = std::for_each(is2.begin(), is2.end(), std::move(p));
    p.flush();

    p = std::for_each(is3.begin(), is3.end(), std::move(p));
    p.flush();

    return 0;
}
```